# I am trying to develop Java Mail Client.I am getting error at RecipientType.TO and RecipientType.CC it cannot be resolved or is not a field error

Tags: java, enums, smtp, jakarta-mail, smtpclient

[image][image]                **JavaMailApp**

```
            public class JavaMailApp
            {
                public static void sendMail( Envelope envelope )
                {
        // created properties object
                    Properties props = new Properties();
                    System.out.println(envelope.DestHost);
                    props.put("mail.smtp.host", envelope.DestHost);
                    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                            new javax.mail.Authenticator()
                    {
                        protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                        { return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication("username","password");  }
                    });

                    try {
            //created mime message object
                        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(envelope.Sender));
        // i am getting error here at FROM,TO,CC in the below code
        //i need to modify my message.java file accordingly,could someone help me on this
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.FROM,
                                InternetAddress.parse(envelope.Recipient));
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,
                                InternetAddress.parse(envelope.Recipient));
                        message.setSubject(envelope.subject);
                        message.setText(envelope.text);
            }
           //end of this class
```

I need to modify my Message.java class.I think i need to use the enums to resolve the error.But donot know how to that.Please add some code snippet to Message.java class to make it working.

**Message.java**

```
                 public class Message {
                /* The headers and the body of the message. */
                public String Headers;
                public String Body;

                /* Sender and recipient. With these, we don't need to extract them
                   from the headers. */
             /* Declared Variables */
                private String From;
                private String To;
                private String TO;
                private String CC;
                private String BCC;
               private static final String CRLF = "\r\n";
    /* I need to change the RecipientType accodingly in Message.java file.Could //you please help me in changing this*/
       public static final String RecipientType = null;
             /* Create the message object by inserting the required headers from*/
                public Message(String from, String to, String subject, String text) {
                /* Remove whitespace */
                From = from.trim();
                To = to.trim();
                this.subject = subject;
                this.text = text;
                Headers = "From: " + From + CRLF;
                Headers += "To: " + To + CRLF;
                Headers += "Subject: " + subject.trim() + CRLF;
                 /* Two functions to access the sender and recipient. */
                public String getFrom() {
                return From;
                }
                }
```

Comment: Try to use javax.mail.Message.RecipientType. Have a look into Java Mail API Doc (https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/)

Comment: I have seen it.I guess i need to modify my message.java class accordingly.I was stuck there actually.

Comment: Your Message class is Mapped to UI? What is your Envelope class do?

Comment: Message class handles the message encoded into the mail sending from the sender to receiver ;checks whether both sender and receiver's emaild id's contain @ ;prints message .  Message class is not mapped to UI.I have a separate class for that.

Comment: But you are using envelope class to populate sender and receiver's emaild id'. Why so?

Comment: Your Message class conflicts with the JavaMail Message clash.  Rename your class to keep it simpler.  Also, see these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: Ok i will do that.I believe i need to use the enums to resolve this issue.